# Why does my program to rename .jpg files not number them correctly when there are files with other extensions as well?

Tags: python

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gax90.png)

```
def main():
   path = r'blahblah'
   lst = os.listdir(path)
   len = 0
   for i in lst:
       if i.endswith(".jpg"):
           len+=1
   len_file = int(math.log(len,10))+1
   z_fill_num = len_file
   count=1
   os.chdir(path)
   for count, filename in enumerate(os.listdir(path)):
    if filename.endswith('.jpg'):
        os.rename(filename, 'image_'+str(count+1).zfill(z_fill_num)+'.jpg')
        count+=1
    elif not filename.endswith('.jpg'):
        pass
```

I was modifying script to replace all the filename to `image_001`, `image_002`,... but when there is another extension file beside '.jpg', the script renames the first image file to `image_002` instead of `image_001`. How do I specify to the script that I want to rename only jpg files?

Comment: It's much easier for us to help you if you provide your code in text instead of in an image.

Comment: Just added. sorry about the inconvenience

Comment: You have `count=1` above `os.chdir(path)` then you use `count` as a unpacked variable for `enumerate` then you have `count+=1` inside the loop! Just use `count` with `enumerate` only. If you want to start at `1` say  `enumerate(os.listdir(path), 1)`

Answer (score 0):

You have to change your loop as you enumerate over the list of files and therefore reset the counter on each loop iteration. Change the following line:

```
for count, filename in enumerate(os.listdir(path)):
```

to this:

```
for filename in os.listdir(path):
```

Also, you have to initialize the counter with zero in order to name the first file `image_0000`.

Answer (score 0):

I believe your problem is due to the fact you initialize `count=1` and then use `str(count+1)` in your renaming function, which means the first rename would use 2.

I think you need to change your `rename` line to:

```
os.rename(filename, 'image_'+str(count).zfill(z_fill_num)+'.jpg')
```

Edit: I just saw that you override your `count` variable with the `count` in the for-loop. You shouldn't do that in any scenario. Consider renaming it or not using it at all.

Comment: Yes I just realized that lol thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Suppose I have these files:

```
ls -1
file-a.jpg
file-b.jpg
file-c.jpg
file-d.jpg
file-e.jpg
```

With Python, with [pathlib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html), you could rename them with increasing numbers like so:

```
from pathlib import Path 
w=4
p=Path(base_path)

for i, fn in enumerate(
                sorted(
                    [f for f in p.glob('*.jpg') if f.is_file()],  # sort as appropriate
                        key=lambda x: x.stem), 1):
    new_name=fn.with_name(f"{fn.stem}-{i:0{w}d}{fn.suffix}")
    print(f'Renaming "{fn}" to "{new_name}"')
    fn.rename(new_name)
```

Prints:

```
Renaming "/tmp/test/file-a.jpg" to "/tmp/test/file-a-0001.jpg"
Renaming "/tmp/test/file-b.jpg" to "/tmp/test/file-b-0002.jpg"
Renaming "/tmp/test/file-c.jpg" to "/tmp/test/file-c-0003.jpg"
Renaming "/tmp/test/file-d.jpg" to "/tmp/test/file-d-0004.jpg"
Renaming "/tmp/test/file-e.jpg" to "/tmp/test/file-e-0005.jpg"
```

And results in:

```
ls -1
file-a-0001.jpg
file-b-0002.jpg
file-c-0003.jpg
file-d-0004.jpg
file-e-0005.jpg
```

Answer (score 0):

A simplified version of your code. No need to call `listdir` 2 times.

```
import os
import math


def rename_file():
    path = r'.'
    lst = [x for x in os.listdir(path) if x.endswith(".jpg")]
    z_fill_num = int(math.log(len(lst), 10))+1
    count = 1
    os.chdir(path)
    for filename in lst:
        os.rename(filename, 'image_'+str(count).zfill(z_fill_num)+'.jpg')
        count += 1


rename_file()
```